# Why when using the Adobe DC SDK the Field's ButtonLayout property is unavailable in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, sdk, vba, adobe

My code is fairly standard, if people need to see more I can provide but essentially I am just trying to access a field's ButtonLayout property. I know the field I am accessing is a button, b/c I Added it previously in the code and I can review it once the file saves.

The last line below is the one that doesn't work. I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". I am using MS Access 2016 with the Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library. In contrast I can access the Value, and the BorderStyle properties and set them just fine.

```
Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
jso.getField("buttonImage1")..BorderStyle = "beveled"
jso.getField("buttonImage1").buttonImportIcon CStr(photoSet!Photo)
jso.getField("caption1").Value = CStr(photoSet!Caption)
jso.getField("buttonImage1").ButtonLayout = "1" 'This is the only line that doesn't work
```

Comment: What type is your `jso` variable declared as? Which type has the `ButtonLayout` property?

Comment: What type is your `jso` variable declared as? Which type has the `ButtonLayout` property?

Comment: @ThunderFrame I didn't declare jso as a certain type, I just used Dim jso. The Field Type has the ButtonLayour property so jso.getField(), I think, returns a Field Type.